# Яке значення, походження, та ареал розповсюдження слова "вихрянка"?

Tags: іменники, семантика

Чи є вживаним слово "вихрянка" (якщо так, то в якому регіоні або діалекті) та яке його значення?

Знаю це слово з Полтавщини. Цікаво дізнатися, яке його походження та з'ясувати межі розповсюдження.

Comment: Вітаю на сайті Ukrainian.SE! Дякую за питання, справді цікаво дізнатися більше про це слово. Ви могли би додати до свого питання інформацію про те, що означає це слово у вашому реґіоні? Так може бути легше шукати. Можете натиснути під вашим текстом на Edit і додати інформацію.